# ToggleButton - how to untoggle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using a ToggleButtonGroup in my to-do list to have my input categorized as today/tomorrow/this week/no date. If no button is toggled, todo items will go under 'no date', else it will fall in one of the other 3 categories.
My problem is, when I start the app and input a todo without toggling anything, the todo will be properly sorted under 'no date'. However, once I toggle/untoggle any of the [today/tomorrow/this week] options, I can no longer get anything to be sorted under 'no date'. How can I fix this?

Class containing the toggle:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import shortid from 'shortid'
    import { Button, ButtonGroup, MenuItem, Select, TextField, InputBase } from '@material- 
    ui/core'
    import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from '@material-ui/lab'
    
    export default class TodoForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        text: '',
        date: ''
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleToggleChange = (e, value) => {
        if (this.state.date == value) {
            this.setState({
                date: ''
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                date: value
            })
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        // If input field empty, do nothing.
        if (this.state.text === '') {
            return
        }

        // Submit the form.
        this.props.onSubmit({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            text: this.state.text,
            date: this.state.date,
            complete: false
        })

        // Empty out input field after todo has been submitted.
        this.setState({
            text: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="td-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="td-form-input"><InputBase 
                    fullWidth={true}
                    name="text" 
                    value={this.state.text} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    placeholder="What do you need to get done?"
                    variant="outlined"
                />
                </div>
                
                <div className="td-form-buttons">
                <ToggleButtonGroup value={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleToggleChange} name="date" id="date-select" exclusive={true} size="small">
                    <ToggleButton value="today">Today</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton value="week">This week</ToggleButton>
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
                <Button className="mui-add" onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant="contained"
                    style={{
                        maxWidth: '36px', 
                        maxHeight: '36px', 
                        minWidth: '36px', 
                        minHeight: '36px', 
                        borderRadius: '36px', 
                        margin: '16px'}}
                >+</Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Class containing the todos:

```
   import React from 'react'
import { Button, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
import RemoveCircleOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircleOutline';

export default props => (
    <div className={props.todo.complete ? "" : "td-itemBackground"}>
        <div className={props.todo.complete ? "td-itemCompleted" : "td-item"}>
            <Button onClick={props.toggleComplete} 
                style={{
                    maxWidth: '36px', 
                    maxHeight: '36px', 
                    minWidth: '36px', 
                    minHeight: '36px', 
                    borderRadius: '36px', 
                    margin: '16px'}}
            >
                <RemoveCircleOutlineIcon/>
            </Button>
            <div 
                style={{
                    textDecoration: props.todo.complete ? "line-through" : ""
                }} 
                onClick={props.toggleComplete}
            >
                <div className="td-text">{props.todo.text}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Can you include the component that renders the todo items?

Comment: @DrewReese [They are not implemented as radios](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.js#L97) and can be toggled off. Would be kind of pointless to have a toggle button that can't be toggled. What you describe would be a RadioButton and RadioButtonGroup. Also I think that OP doesn't want to have a "no date" toggle. No button toggled means "no date".

Comment: @DrewReese Well if you can look up source code you should maybe do it before expressing guesses that turn out to be wrong? Or as the library used here is tagged it would also be easy to look into the docs. I don't see any reason to wrongly point OP towards an issue that doesn't exist and can be ruled out that easy.

Comment: @trix that is correct.
I do not want to have a 'no date' button - I want that to be the choice when none of the other 3 toggles are chosen.

Comment: The toggle can be properly toggled 'off', but the problem is it does not change the state back to 'no date'. 'no date' only works Before I toggle anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am seeing the toggle button group returns null if nothing is selected. So you could check for null and set for no date .  Here is the toggle button example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/j2wp0?file=/demo.js

```js
handleToggleChange = (e, value) => {
  if (value === null) {
    this.setState({
      date: ''
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      date: value
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the handleToggleChange code to below so the date will properly set back to be empty when a button is untoggled. Not sure if the best way to do it so open to other suggestions.

```
  handleToggleChange = (e, value) => {
        if (this.state.date == 'today' || this.state.date == 'tomorrow' || this.state.date == 'week') {
            this.setState({
                date: ''
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                date: value
            })
        }
    }
```